# Conflicting types for 'SecRandomCopyBytes'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get an error on xCode when I'm trying to archive a new version of my app and I can't figurate out where it come from and how can I fix it.

Look at the printscreen from xcode: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOOr0.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 11 changed the signature of that method.

You can try this

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 110000
extern int SecRandomCopyBytes(SecRandomRef rnd, size_t count, void *bytes) __attribute__((weak_import));
#else
extern int SecRandomCopyBytes(SecRandomRef rnd, size_t count, uint8_t *bytes) __attribute__((weak_import));
#endif
```

Source : https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/248

Comment: You suggest to replace that line with those 4 lines ?

Comment: @AdrianVidican Yes

Comment: It is written in object-c so it not gonne work. Anyway, the issues is because RNCryptor need to be update to 3.0.5 but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Yes, RNCryptor developers will need to fix it with replacement of these line. Don't know it is fixed or not. For the time being you can replace these yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on macOS

replacing with

```
extern int SecRandomCopyBytes(SecRandomRef rnd, size_t count, void * bytes) __attribute__((weak_import));
```